# Is it possible to declare a local variable in an if statement or a loop (In JavaScript)

Tags: javascript

I'm having hard time understanding this:
I know you can declare a variable inside a function but only then it would be local. On the other hand can I declare a local variable inside an if statement or a while/ do...while / for loop ? and if I can, would the variable be used only locally in each of the statements ?, is it a good behavior to do so ( Declaring local variables) inside an if statement or a loop finally, what are the possible situations that I might run into and need to declare a variable inside and if statement or a loop?

Comment: With ES 6 you have new keyword "let" for block scope. For earlier version you have to wrap content of if block in a self invoking function to isolate scope from parent.

Comment: You should also look into hoisting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ES5 only supports function level scope.

ES6 introduces the [`let` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) which allows block level scope.

It is useful for such things as generating closures in a loop.